# How to do the pagination when URL change randomly

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination

I have an issue, I would like to scrap all french stocks (10 pages) through this website : https://www.zonebourse.com/bourse/actions/Europe-3/France-51

but when I go to the 2nd page, the end of the url is random, for example :
once it's zonebourse.com/bourse/actions/Europe-3/France-51/**_BF3L50/**
then another time it's zonebourse.com/bourse/actions/Europe-3/France-51/**_4FXnaa/**
etc
it's the same issue for the others pages too ..

there is no pattern ! How can I do ?

Here my code if the url was
zonebourse.com/bourse/actions/Europe-3/France-51/**1**
zonebourse.com/bourse/actions/Europe-3/France-51/**2**
...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = []

for i in range(10):
  url = 'https://www.zonebourse.com/bourse/actions/Europe-3/France-51/' + str(i)
  response = requests.get(url)

  if response.ok:
     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
     tds = soup.findAll('td')
    
      for td in tds:
        a = td.find('a')
        if a != None:
          link = a['href']
          if link.startswith('/cours/action/'):
              links.append('https://www.zonebourse.com'+link)

print(links)
```

thanks !

Comment: Seems like it's a preventive measure to stop users like you, scraping there website, you'd have to look and see how they're generating the id's (most likely server side) to determine active page index of the user

Comment: you should first search all links on other page. And if page use JavaScript to generate HTML then it may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

json_data = {
    "TRBC": 0,
    "TRBC_chain": [""],
    "aSectors": [[], [], [], [], []],
    "aLists": [[], [], [], []],
    "markets": [
        40,
        43,
        44,
        45,
        46,
        47,
        48,
        49,
        50,
        51,
        53,
        54,
        55,
        56,
        57,
        58,
        59,
        60,
        61,
        62,
        63,
        64,
        67,
        69,
        70,
        71,
        72,
        73,
        74,
        75,
        76,
        77,
        78,
        79,
        80,
        81,
        82,
    ],
    "capi_min": 2,
    "capi_max": 10,
    "liqu_min": 0,
    "liqu_max": 10,
    "tri": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "ord": ["N", "N", "N", "D", "N", "N"],
    "special_option_news": "",
    "special_option_date": "",
    "special_dynamic": "",
    "special_partner": "",
    "result_mode": 7,
    "crit": [],
    "page": 1,
    "sMode": "AF2",
}

api_url = "https://www.zonebourse.com/outils/mods_a/moteurs_results.php?ResultMode=7&model=3"

all_data = []
for json_data["page"] in range(1, 3):
    data = {
        "Req": json.dumps(json_data),
        "bJSON": "true",
        "scrollMode": "false",
    }

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.post(api_url, data=data).content, "html.parser"
    )

    for row in soup.table.select("tr")[1:]:
        tds = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for td in row]
        all_data.append(tds)

headers = [
    "col0",
    "Société",
    "Cours",
    "col3",
    "Capitalisation (M$)",
    "Varia. 1janv",
    "Secteur",
    "col7",
]
print(pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=headers).head().to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | col0 | Société | Cours | col3 | Capitalisation (M$) | Varia. 1janv | Secteur | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | LVMH MOËT HENNESSY LOUIS VUITTON.. EUR | 647.5 |  | 332 839 | -8.97% | Habillement et accessoires - Autres |  |
| 1 |  | NESTLÉ S.A. CHF | 114.58 |  | 326 734 | -9.64% | Industrie agroalimentaire - Autres |  |
| 2 |  | ROCHE HOLDING AG CHF | 315.4 |  | 266 801 | -16.54% | Pharmacies - Autres |  |
| 3 |  | NOVO NORDISK A/S DKK | 792.5 |  | 242 615 | 8.12% | Pharmacies - Autres |  |
| 4 |  | SHELL PLC GBX | 2290 |  | 198 550 | 44.25% | Pétrole et gaz - compagnies intégrées |  |